# Angular `Injector` is not helping with circular dependency

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I've got a circular dependency in my services in Angular (v4, using CLI). I understand that circular dependencies should be avoided; just assume for the sake of argument that I can't influence that.

I've read many examples that suggest using `Injector` to solve this.  In my case, it isn't working - I'll still get the `Can't resolve all parameters for MyService...` error.

Even if I just create a method that is NEVER called in the offending service like this:

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';

import { MyService } from '../my.service';


@Injectable()
export class SomeService{

   constructor(private injector:Injector){}

    test() {//I don't call this anywhere
        setTimeout(() => this.injector.get(MyService).doStuff());
    }
}
```

...it will still generate the error.  If I simply comment out that one line in the `test()` method, everything works.

I am even using `SomeService` the same way - it is called using `injector.get` - so the `injector.get` call is the only thing making the circular dependency in either direction.

Why is this working for so many people but I still get the error?  Is this related to the use of Angular CLI somehow?  ...or something that changed for Angular 4?

[This plunker helps demonstrate the issue.](https://plnkr.co/edit/ktJTEq6QTF8nZdt8qela?p=preview)  Please understand this was taken from a large application and this minimal example, by itself, demonstrates poor design - but it exposes the issue.

Comment: Can you reproduce it in plunker?

Comment: where is the circular dependency you're talking about? the class `SomeService` has a method `test` which get's the service `MyService` from `DI`.. here is a plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/7uIjUNrwABAAPF28gpzn?p=preview

Comment: In my case MyService takes in SomeOtherService which takes in SomeService, which uses MyService.  I'll try to get a minimal repo going that reproduces it.

Comment: OK - I've added a plunker that shows the error.  Yes, it is confusing but such is the nature of the problem.  Also, I'm trying to extract this from a large application so you may find some issues with the plunker example - I'll see if I've made the same errors in the source application, otherwise I'll revise the plunker accordingly.